# Is it valid to truncate data to K-S test part of the data?

Tags: truncation, kolmogorov-smirnov

I am comparing the distributions of two sets of -log10(p-values) using KS test. Let me call them X and Y. When I plotted an X versus Y QQ plot, there was an obvious inflation at the right side of the distributions (high -log10(pvalues)). However the KS test comparing X and Y was not significant due to the fact that the majority of the data points fell on the 1:1 linear line on the left. When I excluded the linear part of the distributions and perform KS test only on the inflated part, the KS test was significant. My question is whether it is valid to perform KS test on part of the data for example the inflated part in a QQ plot?

Comment: Might be better suited for math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [math.se]